# Buildroot cannot make with glibc

Tags: linux, makefile, buildroot

When I try to run make after finishing buildroot configuration for Raspberry Pi 4, I have following error:

```
mkdir -p /media/adrian/DyskB/buildroot/buildroot/output/build/glibc-2.31-49-g6f3459f9859a7b506c64fa1823769ab631072c6e/build
# Do the configuration
(cd /media/adrian/DyskB/buildroot/buildroot/output/build/glibc-2.31-49-g6f3459f9859a7b506c64fa1823769ab631072c6e/build; PATH="/media/adrian/DyskB/buildroot/buildroot/output/host/bin:/media/adrian/DyskB/buildroot/buildroot/output/host/sbin:/home/adrian/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/home/adrian/Software/scilab-6.0.2/bin" AR="/media/adrian/DyskB/buildroot/buildroot/output/host/bin/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabihf-ar" AS="/media/adrian/DyskB/buildroot/buildroot/output/host/bin/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabihf-as" LD="/media/adrian/DyskB/buildroot/buildroot/output/host/bin/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabihf-ld" NM="/media/adrian/DyskB/buildroot/buildroot/output/host/bin/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabihf-nm" CC="/media/adrian/DyskB/buildroot/buildroot/output/host/bin/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabihf-gcc" GCC="/media/adrian/DyskB/buildroot/buildroot/output/host/bin/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabihf-gcc" CPP="/media/adrian/DyskB/buildroot/buildroot/output/host/bin/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabihf-cpp" CXX="/media/adrian/DyskB/buildroot/buildroot/output/host/bin/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabihf-g++" FC="/media/adrian/DyskB/buildroot/buildroot/output/host/bin/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabihf-gfortran" F77="/media/adrian/DyskB/buildroot/buildroot/output/host/bin/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabihf-gfortran" RANLIB="/media/adrian/DyskB/buildroot/buildroot/output/host/bin/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabihf-ranlib" READELF="/media/adrian/DyskB/buildroot/buildroot/output/host/bin/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabihf-readelf" STRIP="/media/adrian/DyskB/buildroot/buildroot/output/host/bin/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabihf-strip" OBJCOPY="/media/adrian/DyskB/buildroot/buildroot/output/host/bin/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabihf-objcopy" OBJDUMP="/media/adrian/DyskB/buildroot/buildroot/output/host/bin/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabihf-objdump" AR_FOR_BUILD="/usr/bin/ar" AS_FOR_BUILD="/usr/bin/as" CC_FOR_BUILD="/usr/bin/gcc" GCC_FOR_BUILD="/usr/bin/gcc" CXX_FOR_BUILD="/usr/bin/g++" LD_FOR_BUILD="/usr/bin/ld" CPPFLAGS_FOR_BUILD="-I/media/adrian/DyskB/buildroot/buildroot/output/host/include" CFLAGS_FOR_BUILD="-O2 -I/media/adrian/DyskB/buildroot/buildroot/output/host/include" CXXFLAGS_FOR_BUILD="-O2 -I/media/adrian/DyskB/buildroot/buildroot/output/host/include" LDFLAGS_FOR_BUILD="-L/media/adrian/DyskB/buildroot/buildroot/output/host/lib -Wl,-rpath,/media/adrian/DyskB/buildroot/buildroot/output/host/lib" FCFLAGS_FOR_BUILD="" DEFAULT_ASSEMBLER="/media/adrian/DyskB/buildroot/buildroot/output/host/bin/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabihf-as" DEFAULT_LINKER="/media/adrian/DyskB/buildroot/buildroot/output/host/bin/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabihf-ld" CPPFLAGS="-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64" CFLAGS="-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64  -Os  " CXXFLAGS="-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64  -Os  " LDFLAGS="" FCFLAGS=" -Os " FFLAGS=" -Os " PKG_CONFIG="/media/adrian/DyskB/buildroot/buildroot/output/host/bin/pkg-config" STAGING_DIR="/media/adrian/DyskB/buildroot/buildroot/output/host/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabihf/sysroot" INTLTOOL_PERL=/usr/bin/perl CFLAGS="-O2 " CPPFLAGS="" CXXFLAGS="-O2 " ac_cv_path_BASH_SHELL=/bin/sh libc_cv_forced_unwind=yes libc_cv_ssp=no ac_cv_prog_MAKE="/usr/bin/make -j5" /bin/bash /media/adrian/DyskB/buildroot/buildroot/output/build/glibc-2.31-49-g6f3459f9859a7b506c64fa1823769ab631072c6e/configure --target=arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabihf --host=arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabihf --build=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu --prefix=/usr --enable-shared  --with-pkgversion="Buildroot" --disable-profile --disable-werror --without-gd --enable-obsolete-rpc --enable-kernel=5.4 --with-headers=/media/adrian/DyskB/buildroot/buildroot/output/host/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabihf/sysroot/usr/include)
checking build system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking host system type... arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabihf
checking for arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabihf-gcc... /media/adrian/DyskB/buildroot/buildroot/output/host/bin/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabihf-gcc
checking for suffix of object files... configure: error: in `/media/adrian/DyskB/buildroot/buildroot/output/build/glibc-2.31-49-g6f3459f9859a7b506c64fa1823769ab631072c6e/build':
configure: error: cannot compute suffix of object files: cannot compile
See `config.log' for more details
make[1]: *** [package/pkg-generic.mk:240: /media/adrian/DyskB/buildroot/buildroot/output/build/glibc-2.31-49-g6f3459f9859a7b506c64fa1823769ab631072c6e/.stamp_configured] Błąd 1
make: *** [Makefile:84: _all] Błąd 2
```

How can I repair this? `Błąd` = `Error` in my language

Comment: Did you look at `config.log`, as suggested?

Comment: Only after your suggestion, sorry :D There is repeated line `/media/adrian/DyskB/buildroot/buildroot/output/build/glibc-2.31-49-g6f3459f9859a7b506c64fa1823769ab631072c6e/configure: line 2635: /media/adrian/DyskB/buildroot/buildroot/output/host/bin/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabihf-gcc: No such file or directory'.` Will be helpfull to paste full file content or this is enough? I'm not sure, but I have seen this name before, do I need to change toolchain? I'm using currently buildroot toolchain.

Comment: Looks like your cross-compiler is missing or not in your `PATH`. Is there a working cross-compiler `/media/adrian/DyskB/buildroot/buildroot/output/host/bin/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabihf-gcc`?

Comment: Doesn't exist, I only found arm-buildroot-linux-uclibcgnueabihf-gcc.

Comment: There is probably an inconsistency with your configuration. You apparently declared somewhere that you will be using the lightweight `uClibc` but the toolchain expected by buildroot is that of a regular `libc`. Personally I would restart from scratch, paying attention to the toolchain and library options.

Comment: Okay, thanks for your help. I'm currently trying to build it with external toolchain, I hope it will works, if not, I will try different things.

Comment: After such global changes just `rm -rf output/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed toolchain from Buildroot toolchain to external ARM toolchain and it works now. There is need to rebuild all packages, so on first build after changing toolchain I typed `make clean all` instead of pure `make`.

Comment: @lzZy, may be you mean `make clean all` instead of `make clear all`

Comment: @lzZy, It is working, thanks your solution helped me alot, I faced `make clean all` errors, but ignored it and executed `make` and it is working.

Comment: @DRPandya it was long time ago but I think I mean `clean`, thanks for attention, fixed. Glad to read that it helped somebody :)